# What do I type to blacklist b43 in an installed Ubuntu system?

Tags: 12.04, ppc

Initial boot into 12.04 on newworld ppc mac. `b43` driver is missing. To run the live CD I booted with `b43.blacklist=yes` install went fine. Now I am stuck at boot. I want to boot regular Linux (as it's installed, not the live CD), just without loading load b43. I don't know how to tell it to do that.

Is it something like `boot Linux b43.blacklist=yes`? `linux b43...`? How should I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can either make the boot loader give the `b43.blacklist=yes` option to the kernel automatically, or you can add the `b43` module to the blacklist file.

### Booting `b43.blacklist=yes` Every Time

All boot options are set the same way, so you can follow [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-to-set-nomodeset-for-installation) but with `b43.blacklist=yes` instead of `nomodeset`. Or you may prefer [this excellent guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132). (Or [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions).)

To summarize, here's an essentially identical way to what's given in those sources:

1. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while booting. When the GRUB menu comes up, press <kbd>e</kbd> to temporarily edit the first entry. Add `b43.blacklist=yes` to the end of the line that begins with `linux`, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to boot.
2. Once booted and logged in, open a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run these commands to back up and edit your boot loader configuration:

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.old
   gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```
3. In the text editor that opens up, find the line that says:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```

   Change it so it says:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash b43.blacklist=yes"
   ```

   Save the file and quit the text editor.
4. Back in the Terminal, run `sudo update-grub`. Once that's done, reboot to verify it's working.

If you ever need to undo the change, you can run `gedit /etc/default/grub` and remove `b43.blacklist=yes` from that line, or you can restore the backup (overwriting the new file) with `sudo cp /etc/default/grub.old /etc/default/grub`. Either way, you must run `sudo update-grub` again to apply the changes.

### Adding the `b43` Module to the Blacklist File

Custom boot options are not the only way to prevent kernel modules form loading. Another way is to add them to the blacklist file. Usually, this file does not exist initially, and you must create it.

[A complete, general procedure is here.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=166624) But you can follow this shorter procedure:

1. Boot using Step 1 above (under Booting **`b43.blacklist=yes` Every Time**).
2. Open a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt+T</kbd>) and run:

   ```
   echo blacklist b43 | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-b43.conf
   ```
3. Reboot to verify it works.

If at some point you want to undo this, you can run `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-b43.conf`. (Then to load the `b43` module, you'd reboot, or run `sudo modprobe b43`. You're unlikely to want to do that though, since as you said you don't have the `b43` module at all.)