# "b43.blacklist", successful boot - what next for working wireless?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, blacklist

a definite newbie to Ubuntu and despite lots of ignorance, I've understood just enough to have got 12.04 installed and looking good on my old [Acer Aspire 3003Wlmi](http://support.acer.com/acerpanam/notebook/0000/Acer/Aspire3000/Aspire3000sp2.shtml). However, after days of not being able to boot from the hard drive, only via the live USB stick that was used for the install, it seems that it is the wireless card/driver/thingy that makes it hang.

I found and followed [Eliah's solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/240124/what-do-i-type-to-blacklist-b43-in-an-installed-ubuntu-system) to get past the hangs and into the desktop. However, as I understand it, this leaves me with no working wireless connection.

What should I do from here to restore the wireless service, but still be able to log in and use the computer? I've previously installed 12.10 which worked well, wireless network included, but with an awful display resolution, so I assume there is a solution for the earlier OS?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Depends on the wireless card. You could use another driver with some, or look for the solution to the b43 problem. As the last resort, a cheep, well supported USB dongle would do. You can find out the wireless card model by running `lspci | grep -i net` in a terminal window.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the answers - it seems that the need to blacklist b43 was temporary, just to allow the OS to install without hanging.

Following the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx) carefully (my card is the BCM4318), it let me in to install/reinstall b43, restart and boot from the hard drive without a problem. Success!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please use the contact us link at the bottom of this page to ask for your unregistered account and your new registered account to be merged.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've blacklisted `b43` you need a different wireless driver in its stead.

You can see if Ubuntu can find the proprietary Broadcom driver by going to System Settings->Additional Drivers. The one it should find is "Broadcom STA Proprietary Wireless Driver", aka Broadcom wl.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same wlan card in my ancient Dell laptop running Debian stable . I fixed it by following the instructions at wiki.debian.org/wl . Broadcom also a Linux driver page found here http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php